# jquery regex out 0 from cloned element and insert it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'd like to learn how to regex out 0 from all elements inside clone and replace it with var count_rows.

```
//Duplicate table tr for multiple subtitle entry
$("#add_subtitle").on("click", function(){
    var count_rows = $(".subs_row").length;

    $("#sub_0").clone().insertBefore("#append_sub");

    return false;
});
```

markup:

```
<tr valign="top" id="sub_0" data-num="0" class="subs_row">
                    <th scope="row"><label for="subtitle">Subtitle_0</label></th>
                        <td>
                                <input name="subtitle[0][url]" type="text" value="<?php echo $wovies_extra_data[0]['subtitle'][0]['url']; ?>" style="width:280px;">
                                <p class="howto">Url</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <input name="subtitle[0][lang]" type="text" value="<?php echo $wovies_extra_data[0]['subtitle'][0]['lang']; ?>" style="width:100px;">
                                <p class="howto">Language: Label</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <input name="subtitle[0][lang_code]" type="text" value="<?php echo $wovies_extra_data[0]['subtitle'][0]['lang_code']; ?>" style="width:50px;">
                                <p class="howto">Language: Code</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <input name="subtitle_def" type="radio" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php if ($wovies_extra_data[0]['subtitle_def'] == $key) {echo "checked";} ?> style="width:100px;">
                                <p class="howto">Default?</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

oh and how can I make my regex not touch zero in width:50px; ?

Comment: This should help you RegExp : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp
And this [ replace() ] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is probably the wrong way to go here.
I would suggest to use a template system like http://mustache.github.io/ or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

If you really want to replace the zeros inside your existing HTML code you could target only certain attributes:

```
function replaceZero(row) {
    return function (i, value) {
        return value.toString().replace(0, row);
    }
}

var $row = $("#sub_0");
$("label", $row).text(replaceZero(200));
$("input", $row).attr("name", replaceZero(200));
$row.attr("id", replaceZero(200));
```

<kbd>[Fiddle (simplified)](http://jsfiddle.net/U5RMF/)</kbd>
<kbd>[Fiddle (with clone)](http://jsfiddle.net/U5RMF/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, and yes I realized that. So i went with suggested way to create element via jquery. Much easier and cleaner way for sure.